# laravel-adminのフッターを変更する

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

## やりたいこと

laravel-adminを用いて管理画面のフッターを変更する。

### 環境

laravel 5.5
laravel-admin 1.6

[image: 赤枠のところを変更したい]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `vendor/encore/laravel-admin/views` にあるファイルを`resources/views/admin`　にコピーする。
2. `app/Admin/bootstrap.php`に下記のコードを書いてください。

   `app('view')->prependNamespace('admin', resource_path('views/admin'));`
3. `resources/views/admin/partials/footer.blade.php`を更新すると、修正が反映されます。